# how to draw Bitmap/SVG on iphone screen

Tags: iphone, bitmap, drawing

I am quite new to Objective C iOS development. I just want to draw bitmaps/SVG on iPhone screen at random location. I have studied Coregraphics, Quartz2d framework of iPhone but did not find my direction.

Answer (score 1):

I know two frameworks for drawing svg images. https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit and https://github.com/destman/SVGView.
I'm playing now with second one and you could find my fork on github.

Answer (score 1):

If your needs are modest, the easiest way to draw SVG files on iOS is to use a UIWebView:

```
[myWebView loadData:rawSVGData MIMEType:@"image/svg+xml" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

You can set various properties on the webView, like backgroundColor, opaque, and scalesPageToFit, to customize it. It's not fast and doesn't do everything well, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [UIImage Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you will find:

```
Drawing Images

    – drawAtPoint:
    – drawAtPoint:blendMode:alpha:
    – drawInRect:
    – drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:
    – drawAsPatternInRect:
```

This will solve your problem.

Edit 1 for  "What if i want to draw SVG instead of Bitmap."

If you just looked on the link above you will find all ready your answer.

> Supported Image Formats
>
> Table 1 lists the file formats that can be read by the UIImage class.
>   Table 1  Supported file formats
>
> Format
>
> Filename extensions
>
> Tagged Image File Format (TIFF)
>
> .tiff, .tif
>
> Joint Photographic Experts Group (JPEG)
>
> .jpg, .jpeg
>
> Graphic Interchange Format (GIF)
>
> .gif
>
> Portable Network Graphic (PNG)
>
> .png
>
> Windows Bitmap Format (DIB)
>
> .bmp, .BMPf
>
> Windows Icon Format
>
> .ico
>
> Windows Cursor
>
> .cur
>
> XWindow bitmap
>
> .xbm

If you want to play with svg take a look at [SVGKit](https://github.com/adamgit/SVGKit).

Comment: What if i want to draw SVG instead of Bitmap.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately, UIImage class doesn't support SVG. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW3

Comment: @ThomasW I know this. You should address the comment to Gjel.

Comment: @Gjel did you tried to find it? Maybe is better for you to red this http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I have imported these file but still having problems.
https://github.com/reklis/calayer-exporter

Still getting an error message of CALayerExporter missing.